# How do I disable all Emacs commands?

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs

Is there a way to easily disable all Emacs commands?
I'm trying to remap some commands I commonly use.

```
; Delete line
(global-set-key "\C-d" 'kill-whole-line)
```

In some contexts this doesn't always delete the whole line.
I assume it's the underlying default commands.

Comment: I'm not sure it makes any sense.

Comment: Globally `C-d` may be bound to something, but major & minor modes may well have their own implementation of `C-d` (like `org-mode` which binds `C-d` to `org-delete-char`), and major and minor mode key maps take precedence over global bindings.

Comment: Disabling all commands means disabling Emacs. The question is unclear as to what is really needed (i.e., what the problem really is) - should be closed unless improved. Seems to be an [X Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/231821).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use the default where C-d deletes a character and C-k kills the line to the right of the cursor?

Regardless, I ran into this problem when I wanted to map C-h to backward delete char and M-h to backward delete word. I did it using global-set-key but it would be overridden by some minor modes. There are longer ways to do it, but the best I found is simply to download the use-package package and use the bind-key* command. It forces your set key to override all other minor modes.